# How to convert a BinaryReader to Stream in C#?

Tags: c#, streamreader, bin, binaryreader

I have to read a ".bin" file fully and pass the stream to a function. I tried it with BinaryReader which worked fine for reading values byte by byte, I want to pass the whole file as a string stream to my function. Usage of StreamReader gives garbage information, it looks like StreamReader can't read a bin file properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what it is that you want to do. Do you want to pass the stream object to your function or the contents of the file? If the latter, do you want to pass the contents of the file as an array of bytes or as a string with each byte represented as hex values?

Comment: Your file probably isn't Unicode text.  You need to understand the file you're reading.

Comment: I need to pass a stream not a binary one, but a string, where I can readlines and etc.

Comment: StreamReader can't read a bin file because it is not unicode?

Comment: To Richard, I actually don't want to process it as bytes, which will be done in a separate function. I have a function that processes hex files for which I used STreamReader, but the problem is this new format "bin" file, which I need to extract the file as a stream and pass to a function that will read line by line and do some checksum calculations. Thanks for the help.

Comment: StreamReader cannot read it because it's not text.  If you know that it is text in a non-standard encoding, pass that encoding to the `StreamReader` constructor and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass binary data around as a `string`. Instead, use `byte[]` which is detached from any `Stream` you might have read it from. It's correct that `StreamReader` is for reading text, so you need to use [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) or just the [`Stream.Read()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) directly. If the stream you're reading from allows seeking (exposed through the [`CanSeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek.aspx) property), you can discover its [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length.aspx) and read all bytes from the stream in one go.

If, however, the stream is very large or doesn't support seeking, you need to be a bit more elaborate when reading by doing it in chunks until the `Read()` method returns `0` (which means the end of the stream has been reached).

There is no [`StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) equivalent for reading binary data, but defining one as an extension method isn't very hard.